# Calculator using Shunting Yard- how to proceed after receiving postfix

Tags: java, shunting-yard

I'm coding a calculator to learn Java. I have recently coded a Shunting Yard algorithm very similar to [this](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-shunting-yard-algorithm/) one. The only differences between my algorithm and the linked one is that I also include an exponent operator. Here are the changes:

```html
leftParen(0), rightParen(1), add(2), subtract(3), divide(4), multiply(5), modulus(6), eos(7), exponent(8), operand(9);
```

And:

```html
private static final int[] isp = {0, 19, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 0, 14};
private static final int[] icp = {20, 19, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 0, 14};
private static final char[] operators = {'(', ')', '+', '-', '/', '*', '%', ' ', '^'};
```

Everything else is the same.

However, I am very new to Java and data structures, and I'm unsure of:

1. How to implement the Shunting Yard algorithm into my Calc class.
2. How to begin processing the postfix provided by the algorithm.

Any advice or examples of these two issues, or other of issues you see, would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a framework of the original code for my calculator, which could only handle simple functions, such as `2+2`. Comments are my ideas for beginning to implement the Shunting Yard algorithm, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. The comments would replace certain lines above/below them. I'm not sure how much of this code is still usable.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public abstract class Calc 
{
    private static BigDecimal num1, num2;

    public static void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Calculator. Type \"exit\" to quit.");
        System.out.print("> ");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
        //ShuntingYard sy = new ShuntingYard();
        //String infix = scan.next();
        String entry = scan.next();

        //while (! (infix.equals("exit")))
        while (! (entry.equals("exit")))
        {    
            //String postfix = sy.postfix(infix);

            String [] numbers = entry.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("[\\+\\-\\/\\*\\%\\^]");        
            String operator = entry.replaceAll("(\\s+|\\d+|\\.)", "");

            BigDecimal [] operands = new BigDecimal[numbers.length];           
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            {
                operands[i] = new BigDecimal(numbers[i]);
            }

            num1 = operands[0];
            num2 = operands[1];

            BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);

            switch (operator)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = Calc.add(num1, num2);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    ...
                case "*":
                    ...
                case "/":
                    ...
                case "^":
                    ...
                case "%":
                    ...
                default:
                System.out.println("Not valid.");
            }

            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.print("> ");
            entry = scan.next();
        }
    }

    public static BigDecimal add(BigDecimal num1, BigDecimal num2)
    {
        BigDecimal sum = num1.add(num2);
        return sum;
    }

    public static BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal num1, BigDecimal num2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static BigDecimal multiply(BigDecimal num1, BigDecimal num2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal num1, BigDecimal num2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static BigDecimal exponentiate(BigDecimal num1, BigDecimal num2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static BigDecimal modulus(BigDecimal num1, BigDecimal num2)
    {
        ...
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about just implementing the algorithm? What is the problem with that?

Comment: @ThreeFx Well, the algorithm will only provide a postfix expression, it won't actually calculate anything for me. For example: 
`Shunting Yard Algorithm Test`
 
`Enter infix expression`
`1+2*3/4-5%6*7/8+9-1`
 
`Postfix expression : 123*4/+56%7*8/-9+1-` I need a little help on understanding how to begin processing the postfix expression.

Comment: Processing a postfix expression is actually **much** easier than processing an infix expression. Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) Wikipedia article to solve your problem.

Comment: @ThreeFx Thanks, that wiki article clears it up. I will try to code that following their pseudocode and the example table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the shunting yard algorithm:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/Shunting-yard_algorithm#Java

Once you have this working, it's simply:

1) take an operator from the ops stack, and according to the operator

2) take one or two elements from the operand stack, apply the operator

3) push the result and go back to 1) till done.